# .net core 2 how to implement repository properly

Tags: c#, repository, entity-framework-core

I am struggling with how to properly implement repositories. All data operations have to be done via stored procedures (I do not want to argue if it is right or wrong)

In Startup, I register `dbcontext`. The `dbcontext` allows me to read data from database thanks to `DbQuery` and `DbSet` objects.

But i also need to implement repository interface, which i tried. But my implementation allows me to only execute stored procedures via `ExecuteSqlCommand`, but I am not able to use `DbQuery` or `DBSet` objects to retrieve data.

I would like to use `DbQuery`, `DbSet` and also `ExecuteSqlCommand` in one Repository implementation. How to do that ? Should i create `new DbContext` in each repository or to share `DbContext via dependency injection` or should repository inherit `DbContext` ?

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<Database>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**DbContext**

```
public class Database : DbContext
    {

        public Database(DbContextOptions<Database> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbQuery<Business> Business { get; set; }

        // working
        public IEnumerable<Business> GetBusiness(int id)
        {
            var query = @"exec query.usp_GetBusiness @id";
            var p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
            return Business.FromSql(query, p1).ToList();
        }
}
```

**BusinessRepository.cs**
I have custom repository, which enables executing stored procedures

```
    public class BusinessRepository :IBusinessRepository
        {
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;
            private readonly DatabaseFacade database;

            public BusinessRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
            {
                DbContextOptions dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
                    .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                    .Options;

                database = new DbContext(dbContextOptions).Database;

                _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
            }

            // working
            public void UpdateBusinessName(string Name)
            {
                database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec command.usp_UpdateBusinessName @user, @name",
                    new SqlParameter("user", _httpAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name),
                    new SqlParameter("name", Name)
                );
            }

            // this does not work, because repository does not inherit from dbContext
            public virtual DbQuery<Business> Business { get; set; }

            // not working, Business.FromSql(query, p1) returns ArgumentNullException !
            public IEnumerable<Business> GetBusiness(int id)
            {
                var query = @"exec query.usp_GetBusiness @id";
                var p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
                return Business.FromSql(query, p1).ToList();
            }
        }
```

***The question bottom line***

Is it good idea to wrap all repositories to some masterRepository object and call repositories like `masterRepository.businessRepository.GetBusiness()` the advantage is that i can input only one object as parameter which contains all commands, the disadvantage is that i create instance of repositories i dont use for each request. What do you think ?

I know this is complex question, so i am very thankful for the answers.

Comment: "Is it good idea to wrap all repositories to some masterRepository" No, that's a terrible idea. Why would a CarRepository depend on a PersonRepository? The only idea of repositories is for you to be able to separate and test each part on its own, and you are asking to do just the opposite. Also, if you are going to use EF Core just for executing raw SQL, you will be MUCH better off using Dapper

Comment: Don't pass in the IHttpContextAccessor, that should be a parameter to UpdateBusinessName. Database can be a parameter in the constructor (assuming you have registered it with DI), so no need to do that DbContextOptionsBuilder bit.  In some ways, you are fighting against the .netcore principals, which might be why things aren't quite what you expect.

Comment: Also, creating dependencies in classes goes *against* the Dependency Injection pattern, as @Neil stated. Creating a new context manually each time is a huge waste of resources and can only lead to problems (it's not a good idea to keep the `IConfiguration` object alive long)

Comment: Thank you for replies, so if i pass `DbContext` via DI into contstructor, which seems like a good idea because the class will not have dependency inside. How can I use `DbQuery` and `DbSet` objects ? I though that this objects are functional only in class which inherit from DbContext.


**@Neil** why is passing `IHttpContextAccessor` into repository bad idea ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - "a huge waste of resources" is very disputable. DbContexts are smart and work well with the connection pool. The right approach is very situation dependent.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've seen enough memory problems when passing around `IConfiguration` already. Maybe the statement wasn't clear enough, blame my non-native English :) DbContext instances are scoped by default, so they are created quite often with the default `AddDbContext` call

Comment: If you’re just using the Execute SQL command, why bother with the hassle of EF and DbContext at all?

Comment: @Robert Perry EF is default recommended library for data access, why not to learn it to use it on simple scenario first ? But i am still looking for a way how to implement it properly.

Comment: @Muflix - If you're bypassing all of the features of EF and just calling stored procedures; there are better tools for the job. Something like Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is a far more appropriate library for your needs IMO

Comment: @RobertPerry thank you, but even all queries were generated by EF and only few by stored procedures because of performance optimalization i am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed advice from comments and this is my first working solution for my scenario. It maybe not best practice but at least it is working.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**DbContext**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppContext (DbContextOptions<AppContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbQuery<Business> Business { get; set; }

    }
```

**BusinessRepository.cs**

```
 public class BusinessRepository :IBusinessRepository
    {
        private readonly AppContext _context;

        public BusinessRepository(AppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // working
        public IEnumerable<Business> GetBusiness(int id)
        {
             var query = @"exec query.usp_GetBusiness @id";
             var p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
             return _context.Business.FromSql(query, p1).ToList();
        }

        // working
        public void UpdateBusinessName(string name, string user)
        {
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec command.usp_UpdateBusinessName @user, @name",
                new SqlParameter("user", user),
                new SqlParameter("name", name)
            );
        }
}
```